# Find the distribution of $Y$,

Tags: probability

Suppose that random variable $X$ is uniformly distributed over the interval $(0,1)$; that is, $f_X(x)=I_{(0,1)}(x)$. Assume that the conditional distribution of $Y\mbox{ given }X=x$ has a binomial distribution with parameters $n\mbox{ and }p=x$; i.e.,

$P[Y=y|X=x]=\displaystyle{n \choose y}x^y(1-x)^{n-y}$
for $y=0,1,...,n $

Find the distribution of $Y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $X$ is uniform on $(0,1)$,
$$\Pr(Y=y) =\int_0^1 \binom{n}{y} x^y(1-x)^{n-y}\,dx.$$
The $\binom{n}{y}$ comes out, but we still have an unpleasant integral to do. One can get at it by establishing a reduction formula. But luckily, it is a well-known integral, and  has [already been done for you.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

When the smoke clears, you will find that a "miracle" has occurred, and ultimately we end up with a discrete uniform on $[0,n]$.